# How can I stop windows re-positioning after waking up monitors?

Tags: kde, multi-monitor, kubuntu, plasma5

I have a laptop with multi-monitor setup, one is HDMI and the other is VGA. I have the energy saving setting set to dim screen after 5 min and switch screen off after 10 min, with suspends set to never. I lock my PC and after 10 had passed, when I re-login all open windows will moved to the laptop screen! I would like to keep all windows in place without having to reorder them each time. Is there a solution to this?

System Information:

- List item
- OS: Kubuntu 18.04 64-bit
- KDE Plasma Version: 5.12.6
- Graphics Card: Intel Corporation Skylake GT2 [HD Graphics 520] (rev 07)

Answer (score 3):

Use this simple shellscript before and after suspend:

```
#!/bin/bash
# Get the coordinates of the active window's
#    top-left corner, and the window's size.
# This can be saved & loaded

getpos(){
    wmctrl -l -G > /dev/shm/winposs
}
setpos(){
    while read -r id g x y w h host app;do
        IFS=" ," read ta tb a b c d <<<$(xprop -id "$id" _NET_FRAME_EXTENTS 2>/dev/null)
        [ -z $d ] && continue
        wmctrl -i -r $id -e "$g,$((x-$d)),$((y-$c)),$((w+$d+$b)),$((h+$c+$a))" 2>/dev/null
    done < /dev/shm/winposs
}

case $1 in
    get) echo getting window positions
         getpos
    ;;
    set) echo setting window positions
         setpos
    ;;
    run) getpos
         shift
         ${@}
         setpos
    ;;
    *) echo "Usage: ${0##*/}"' [get|set|run <command>]'
    ;;
esac
```

Comment: i think this script has a syntax error on line 11, but i cant figure out how ti fix it!

Comment: Replace first `sh` to `bash`.